# How to run a formula on each cell in a range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a excel VBA which will go through a specific range `(A1 to C5)` and if `B` column is zero, copy `C` column data into `D`

[image]

Dont hav much experience with excel VBA, I have tried the code (which created with help of formula), but no luck.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

Dim FLrange As Range
Set FLrange = Range("A1:C5")

For Each FLrange In ActiveWindow.RangeSelection

If FLrange.Value = 0 Then D$ = C$

Next FLrange

End Sub
```

can someone correct if it is wrong

Comment: Does this need to be VBA? You could use an actual formula. Using your example, in cell D2 use this formula and copy down: `=IF(B2=0,C2,"")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @tigeravatar about the formula option but if you really want VBA start with this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim FLrange As Range
    Set FLrange = Range("B2:B5")

    For Each cell In FLrange
        If cell.Value = 0 Then cell.Offset(0, 2) = cell.Offset(0, 1)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine. I have question here. If I want to run a formula, instead of fetching value from another cell, How can I mention that. for example if value matches zero, I need to run a formula E+F

Comment: If I follow you correctly, I think your looking for something of this nature: `=IF(B2=0,E2+F2,"")`  Or do you mean from VBA you want to set the cell formula?

Comment: Yes, but looking for VBA for same

Comment: Okay, inside the same loop above replace the `If` statement with this: `If cell.Value = 0 Then cell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=E" & cell.Row & "+F" & cell.Row`

Comment: Sorry to ask one more doubt. If I want to run this formula on same cell where we are doing cell.Value = 0, (column B2 to B5 here), How can I do that. ?  Do I need to mention offset as `cell.Offset(0, 0).Formula` then ?

Comment: Or just `cell.Formula` should do it.  Be careful with macros in this case because there is no undo if you overwrite data that you can't afford to lose.  Always make a copy of your workbook when developing macros for existing data.  Cheers

Comment: Thanks much for helping me to understand it.My final question, I need to use the same condition on another sheet related to it, but their the formula I need to check is bit complicated. I need to do `=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)` as `cell.formula'. Can you help me how to add that ? I have tried in simple way like 'If cell.Value = 0 Then cell.Formula = "=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)"' The problem is this formula always checking 'C$2', but not the relative cells like D$2, E$2 etc

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean since your example is changing the column letter and not the row.  I'm headed out shortly so you may want to post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

this code will do exactly what you asked for:

```
Sub myMacro()
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("B2:B5")

For Each cell In myRange
    If Range(cell.Address).value = 0 Then
        Range(cell.Offset(0, 2).Address).value = Range(cell.Offset(0, 1).Address).value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

However what you have requested is easily possible simply using an equation.  I am assuming you are looking for a grander VBA solution and you only provided a sample of your end goal for simplicities sake.  If NOT, why not just use if/than functions in the cell...